# Query based on different date and product ids

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to build the query based on the attached image.

[image]

I want to get the sum of quantity (product Id wise) from "transaction" table where date is greater than the date of first table. for example ProductID 1254 should return 7.

Thanks to all!

Comment: There are two tables in that image. The right one is obviously the Transaction table, but what's the left one?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select p.ProductID, sum(t.Qty)
from Products p
left join TransactionData t
on (t.ProductID = p.ProductID) AND
  (t.Date >= p.Date)
group by p.ProductID
```